# Interpretation of my neural network output

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network

I am using a NN with activation function:

F = 1 / ( 1 + e^(-4.9*S) )
S is the sum of inputs

the network has 1 output node and is interpreted as states of a motor
the motor has 3 states:  1-clockwise motion 2-counterclockwise motion 3-locked

the question is how should i interpret the output?
is it correct to say for example:

- if ( output > 0.8 ) then clockwise motion
- if ( 0.2 > output < 0.8 ) then locked
- if ( output < 0.2 ) then counterclockwise motion

i mean is it correct to interpret the output as it has 3 states? does a single node have the power to have 3 states? or i must have 3 different nodes for 3 states?

**another way to ask this:** does the value between 0.2 and 0.8 mean anything or it is just undecided?

**another related question:** can a single output node mean degrees of a motor? for example 0->0  degress 0.5->180 degress 1->360 degress ...

Answer (score 1):

That depends entirely on your neural network.  For that one you described, I would say that it *could* represent the middle state, or it could represent 'confused neural network'.

Thus, I would recommend having three outputs.  If, for whatever reason, none of them fire, or more than one fires, you know something is broken.

Yes, you could have a neural network output a continuous variable, but it would require somewhat careful tuning, and probably a linear activation function for at least the last layer.

Comment: so you say theoretically there is no problem to interpret the output as 3 states or even more, but it is difficult for the network to handle it... am i correct? any examples someone did this before?

Comment: Basically yes.  In theory, the network should be able to do it.  In practice making it work is harder, possibly will require a larger network, and it is more difficult to tell if something is broken.

Comment: thanks for your answer, please mention a reference talking about this issue if you know any, it will be very helpful

Comment: http://www.tamut.edu/cil/multi-valuedneurons.htm should give you some introduction and links to various articles about multi-valued neurons.

Answer (score 1):

I agree (with zabediah49) that it sounds more sensible with three outputs, one for each state. If the states are mutually exclusive, and it sounds like they are, I even would even consider to have a softmax output instead of sigmoid.

-Ø

Comment: thx for the answer, but the main question is can I interpret my NN's output which has a sigmoid activation function like I asked or not. I can't change my network structure( at least now! )